# Is it possible to surround/encapsulate a property with an operator on top in? (Stacking elements in UI)

Tags: interface, properties, operator

The image represents my idea.

Lets say the green is an operator that simply prints "hi". The other colours are properties of an object displayed. For example, the blue is the name.

[image: properties and operator]

**Is it possible to, whenever I press the name property, the input "goes through" the underlying operator**, so clicking the name will also trigger printing "hi"?

If its possible, how?

When ever I place an operator, they occupy their own space and Im not sure how to "stack" elements (even if its possible). Any idea?